How to highlight C/C++ documentation using Pygments
I want to use Pygments to highlight C/C++ code snippets. I found that the keywords in documentations such as @brief, @param, @return are not highlighted.
/// @brief Writes a string to 'dest' obtained from 'source' by removing all the digits.
/// @param dest Points to a block of memory large enough to hold the result.
/// @param source Points to a null-terminated byte string.
void remove_digits(char *dest, const char *source) {
  // ...
}

Can Pygments be configured or customized to achieve that? What's more, how can I achieve it in LaTeX using the minted package?
